# How can I get a user (not the currently logged in user) by Id, name, email or other search criteria, using UserManager?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity

This should be the simplest thing in the world to do, but I can't find any information about it.

As a temporary solution, I have resorted to this:

```
ApplicationUser user = await db.Users.Where(u => u.Email == email).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

But what I originally imagined I could do was something like this:

```
await ApplicationUser user = userManager.GetUserAsync(email);
```

I already have access to `userManager` in my controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ApplicationUser firstUser = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email)
ApplicationUser secondUser = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id)
ApplicationUser thirdUser= await userManager.FindByNameAsync(name)
```

[image]
You can read full article, and get info about all `userManager` methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FindBy...()` methods to find users by parameters.

[`FindByEmailAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.findbyemailasync) gets the user, if any, associated with the normalized value of the specified email address.

[`FindByEmailAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.findbyidasync) finds and returns a user, if any, who has the specified `userId`.

[`FindByLoginAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.findbyloginasync) retrieves the user associated with the specified external login provider and login provider key.

[`FindByNameAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.findbynameasync) finds and returns a user, if any, who has the specified user name.

```
var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
var user2 = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

var loginProvider = "Github";
var providerKey = "Stian";
var user3 = await userManager.FindByLoginAsync(loginProvider, providerKey);

var user4 = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
```